# Multiline TextBox doesn't display cursor when resized

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am creating a custom control, a custom looking TextBox designed to only allow numeric input. It consists of a plain control, with a TextBox as one of it's properties:

```
class NumericControl : Control
{
    private TextBox text;
    //rest of the code
}
```

This TextBox is drawn inside of the control. It all works very nicely, except that when you press enter it makes this horrible DING noise. To fix this, I thought I'd make the TextBox multiline. However, when I do this, because the font size of the TextBox is changed to resize it, the blinking cursor inside the TextBox appears to disappear, which is a problem because then you can't tell by looking at it whether or not it has focus. If I don't change the font size of the TextBox, the cursor appears and acts normally, however I need the font size to change based on the height of the control, otherwise it doesn't look any good.

The code setting the TextBox properties is as follows, and resides within the constructor of my control:

```
text = new TextBox();
text.AutoSize = false;
text.Left = 10;
text.Top = 2;
text.Text = "0";
text.Multiline = true;
text.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
text.TextChanged += text_TextChanged;
text.LostFocus += text_LostFocus;
this.Controls.Add(text);
```

The font size is changed inside the OnPaint event, and looks like this:

```
text.BackColor = Enabled ? Background : SystemColors.Control; //Fixes an issue I had with disabled TextBox BackColor being able to be changed
text.Font = new Font(TextBox.DefaultFont.FontFamily, (float)(rc.Height * 0.7 - 2), FontStyle.Regular);
text.Width = this.Width - 21;
text.Height = this.Height - 4;
```

How do I both resize the textbox (and font size), and make it multiline while retaining the blinking cursor when it has focus?

Comment: Any reason why you made a control that inherited from `Control` and not `TextBox`?